# UWP application not debugging after upgrading target version & min version

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

UWP application not debugging when target platform changed to  **windows 10, version 1809 (10.0;Build 17763)**.

I am getting the following error while compiling ***application\obj\x64\Debug\App.g.i.cs could not be found***.

But it works when i copy the same file into different folder and compile.
This problem started after updating the target and min version to 17763 build, before that it worked fine.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong in my question to downvote. if i had missed any guidelines please let me know so that i won't repeat the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps..
1) Clean Solution
2) Delete Bin and Obj folder
3) Restart System 
4) Try again

Already Faced the same problem...

Comment: Yeah it works, but i'm facing the same issue again and again after generating the build in release mode. Is there any permanent solution to this

Comment: Certificate is there, and i have also made a build with the same certificate

Comment: Could you tried reopen the project with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yeah i did. same issue still. the only solution that worked is restarting my sytem or changing the folder. I need a permanent solution instead of doing this things everytime

Comment: Which Visual Studio version you used?

Comment: vs 2017 version

Comment: Have you tried update to latest version, or op your project with VS 2019?